# Error in using sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, android-service

I am trying to use sharedpreferences to save an array of boolean and retrieve it by a service when the application is closed. I am experiencing the following error on launch i do not understand it

```
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.GhattasAk.RingMe/com.GhattasAk.RingMe.Main}: java.util.NoSuchElementException
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346): Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:272)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at com.GhattasAk.RingMe.Main.onCreate(Main.java:82)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  ... 11 more
```

below is the code snippets where the sharedpreferences is used

```
public class Main extends ListActivity{
    ArrayList<String> myArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> isChk = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Boolean> isChkb,keysl = new ArrayList<Boolean>();


    Boolean found;
    String number, Name;
    int CallerIndex;
    int ringerMode;
    int NameIndex;
    AudioManager mAudioManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        ringerMode = mAudioManager.getRingerMode();

        Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (people.moveToNext()) {
            NameIndex = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);

            //check if we have a valid column index
            if (NameIndex != -1) {
                Name = people.getString(NameIndex);

                if(myArr.contains(Name)) {
                    // do nothing, as the same String is already in the list
                }
                else {
                    myArr.add(Name.toString());
                }
            }    
        }

        Collections.sort(myArr, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

        boolean[] keys = new boolean[myArr.size()];

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("isChk", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedString = prefs.getString("keys", ",false");
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(savedString, ",");
         for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            keys[i] = Boolean.valueOf(st.nextToken());
          }

for(int i = 0; i<myArr.size();i++)
{
   if(keys[i]){ 
       isChk.add(1);
       isChkb.add(true);
       keysl.add(true);
       }
   else{
       isChk.add(0);  
       isChkb.add(false); //Line 95
       keysl.add(false);
       }
}
```

and then the onstop method to update the values and end

```
 @Override
 protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();  
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("isChk", MODE_PRIVATE);                
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < keysl.size(); i++) {
    str.append(keysl.get(i)).append(",");
    }
    prefs.edit().putString("keys", str.toString()).commit();    

        }
```

after checking the tokensizer if it has more elements in it i got this problem

```
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.GhattasAk.RingMe/com.GhattasAk.RingMe.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at com.GhattasAk.RingMe.Main.onCreate(Main.java:95)
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-08 20:31:34.971: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  ... 11 more
```

Line 95

```
    for(int i = 0; i<myArr.size();i++)
    {
       if(keys[i]){ 
           isChk.add(1);
           isChkb.add(true);
           keysl.add(true);
           }
       else{
           isChk.add(0);  
           isChkb.add(false); This is line 95
           keysl.add(false);
           }
    }
```

Comment: Post this line at com.GhattasAk.RingMe.Main.onCreate(Main.java:95) -- line 95 of Main.java

Comment: for(int i = 0; i<myArr.size();i++)
     {
     if(keys[i]){ 
      isChk.add(1);
      isChkb.add(true);
      keysl.add(true);
      }
     else{
      isChk.add(0);  
      isChkb.add(false);  -- Line 95
      keysl.add(false);
      }
     }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your null pointer is caused because you created the reference to `keysl` but not to `isChkb`.

```
ArrayList<Boolean> isChkb,keysl = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
```

Should be

```
ArrayList<Boolean> isChkb = new ArrayList<Boolean>(), keysl = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
```

It assign the reference just to keysl not to isChkb

---

As you can see:

```
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346): Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:272)
03-08 20:21:36.670: E/AndroidRuntime(346):  at com.GhattasAk.RingMe.Main.onCreate(Main.java:82)
```

`NoSuchElementException` in`java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:272)`

It's caused because you should check if `StringTokenizer` have more elements in it.

This

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(savedString, ",");
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    keys[i] = Boolean.valueOf(st.nextToken());
}
```

Should be something like this

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(savedString, ",");

for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (!st.hasMoreTokens()) break;
    keys[i] = Boolean.valueOf(st.nextToken());
}
```

or better (for me)

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(savedString, ",");

for (int i = 0; i < keys.length && st.hasMoreTokens(); i++) {
    keys[i] = Boolean.valueOf(st.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: i tried that but the application didn't launch and got this error ( check updated)

Comment: You still got the crash? If it's the same crash make sure you check always if there are more tokens.

Comment: if the application is launching for the first time and i called the sharedpreferences get() methods and used the implemented loop with the tokenizer what should happen ? should it crash ? ( when no preferences are present)

Comment: If it's empty there are no tokens to fetch, so `hasMoreTokens()` returns 0 so no for.

Comment: 03-08 20:31:08.502: E/AndroidRuntime(344): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 20:31:08.502: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at com.GhattasAk.RingMe.Main.onCreate(Main.java:95)
03-08 20:31:08.502: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-08 20:31:08.502: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)

Comment: i updated it but it is still crashing :S i added the updated log

Comment: I posted a comment in the question